# How can I compute correlation between two values of a column?

Tags: r

I do not have two different columns (variables) where I can observe their correlation, but instead, I have a binary variable (v2x_regime) where 0 means autocracies, 1 means democracies and I would like to see the correlation between democracies and autocracies regarding SuPDem. How can I do that?

my df is:

| v2x_regime | Year | SuPDem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1990 | -0.581147 |
| 0 | 1991 | -1.581147 |
| 0 | 1992 | 2.371147 |
| 1 | 1990 | -0.581147 |
| 1 | 1991 | -0.471147 |
| 1 | 1992 | -0.601147 |

Comment: Please repost using a reproducible example i.e. "data<-data.frame(v2x_regime = c(0,0,0,1.....) , Year = c(1990, 1991,...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with `Reduce`.

```r
df1 <- 'v2x_regime  Year    SuPDem
0   1990    -0.581147
0   1991    -1.581147
0   1992    2.371147
1   1990    -0.581147
1   1991    -0.471147
1   1992    -0.601147'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(df1), header = TRUE)

Reduce(cor, split(df1$SuPDem, df1$v2x_regime))
#> [1] -0.7911761
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: it gives this following error: Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : incompatible dimensions

Comment: @user19562955 The data you posted are balanced. Can you post a better example, with which the error can be reproduced?